# Maven doesn't use the repository from the global settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, mvn-repo

I have set up an active profile with custom repositories in my "\Program Files\maven\conf" directory but Maven always tries to use the standard URL (repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and fails to download the repositories because of that.
I already tried to debug the process and the correct settings.xml is loaded as 'globalSettings' but it doesn't want to use my custom repositories.

If I add the profiles + repos to the settings.xml in my ".m2"-folder the download works.
How can I force Maven to use the custom URL instead of the "repo.maven.apache.org" one?

Comment: Why do you want to change the global settings.xml? Usually, you only change the one in `.m2`.

Comment: Why does it fail `download the repositories because...` ?

Comment: Because I can change the 'M2_HOME' env variable which contains the directory under 'Program Files' but I think there's no variable for the .m2-Folder. I want to change settings.xml files via environment variables

Comment: The download fails because it tries to download from the standard Maven repository but the required dependencies are in my custom repository

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to use different `settings.xml` is to use the `-s` parameter on command line.

You can use a bat file to set this parameter through environment variables if you want.